# Referring to parts of large JSON files

Tags: python, json

I am currently trying to have python parse JSON similar to the one at https://petition.parliament.uk/petitions/560216.json.
My problem is that the data I need is nested in a lot of parts and I don't know how to tell python which part to take.

A simplified version of the data I need is below

```
{
    "data": {
        "attributes": {
            "signatures_by_country": [
                {
                    "name": "Afghanistan",
                    "code": "AF",
                    "signature_count": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "Algeria",
                    "code": "DZ",
                    "signature_count": 2
                },
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to pull the `"signature_count"` part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code collect what you have asked to a list

```
data = {
    "data": {
        "attributes": {
            "signatures_by_country": [
                {
                    "name": "Afghanistan",
                    "code": "AF",
                    "signature_count": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "Algeria",
                    "code": "DZ",
                    "signature_count": 2
                },
            ]
        }
    }
}

counts = [x['signature_count'] for x in data['data']['attributes']['signatures_by_country']]
print(counts)
```

output

```
[1,2]
```

Count by country below

```
counts = [{x['name']:x['signature_count']} for x in data['data']['attributes']['signatures_by_country']]
```

output

```
[{'Afghanistan': 1}, {'Algeria': 2}]
```

Comment: Ah so that's how it works, Thanks!